# How to read key values from appsettings.json to typescript file using angular4

Tags: json, angular, appsettings

How to read key values from `appsettings.json` to typescript file using angular4

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "Application": {
    "ServiceUrl": "http://localhost:12345",
    "BaseURL": ""
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where this JSON file is located in your Web application, you would be able to use Angular's Http client to do a GET request and fetch it's data. You can even add a typescript interface to expect a result. A bit like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface someInterface {
   foo: string,
   bar: number
}

export class SomeClass {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  data: someInterface;

  someFunc(){
    this.http.get<someInterface>('/path/to/json').subscribe(result => {
       this.data = result;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,this is more useful for me.Where I need to call this someFunc() method to get all the variables before starting my app or before starting other functions